# How do u add a 3 second delay in C# (visual studio 2010)

Tags: c#, .net

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        int randumnum1;
        public Form1()
        {           
            InitializeComponent();          
        }
        public int randumnum()
        {
            Random r = new Random();
            int randumnum = r.Next(15, 30);
            return randumnum;
        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
         randumnum1 = randumnum();
         string strrandumnum = randumnum1.ToString();
         label4.Text = strrandumnum;        
         button2.Text = "New Game";       

        }      

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Random r = new Random();
            int computer = r.Next(1, 4);

            String strrandumnum;            
            if (((Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text)) < 1) || ((Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text)) > 3))
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Invalid input. Remember you can enter numbers between 1 and 3 only", "Error");
                textBox1.Text = "";
            }
            else if  (Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text) == 1)
            {   randumnum1 -= 1;
                strrandumnum = randumnum1.ToString();
                label4.Text = strrandumnum;
                textBox1.Text = "";
            }
            else if (Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text) == 2)
            {
                randumnum1 -= 2;
                strrandumnum = randumnum1.ToString();
                label4.Text = strrandumnum;
                textBox1.Text = "";
            }
            else if (Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text) == 3)
            {
                randumnum1 -= 3;
                strrandumnum = randumnum1.ToString();
                label4.Text = strrandumnum;
                textBox1.Text = "";
            }    
           //I want a 3 second delay right here but nothing seems to work. I tried the
           //thread sleep but it skipped all the other if statements and was messed up.

                randumnum1 -= computer;
                strrandumnum = randumnum1.ToString();
                label4.Text = strrandumnum;
              }
```

Comment: You should be aware that your 'randumnum()' function will not reliably produce a pseudo random number, because you create a new instance of Random each time you call it.

Answer (score 3):

You say in your comment that you tried `Thread.Sleep`, and you're right: that will pause the currently executing thread for 3 seconds, which means your UI will stop responding for those 3 seconds.

What you might try instead is using a [`System.Windows.Forms.Timer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.timer%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), which can be started in your code where you want the delay to happen. It will then fire an event when your delay is complete, and your post-delay code should go in the event handler. This way, your delay can happen without affecting the UI.

Answer (score 1):

I guess one way would be `Thread.Sleep(3000);`. There are a number of ways to do what you want, but based on the code you've provided, that should suffice. Place it where you want the delay.

Comment: Ive tried that it does work but it delays as soon as the button is pressed but i want to delay it after the if statements.

Comment: @user3062166: No, it's delaying after your `if` statements, if that's where you put the code. I suspect your confusion is because - with the `Thread.Sleep` happening there - the UI won't be updated until after the delay has completed. Even though you have set `label4.Text` before the delay, you won't *see* that change until afterwards.

Comment: How would i use  System.Windows.Forms.Timer exactly in my code

Comment: Please explain with more detail, Im a complete novice to c# programming